# Upper limit for java heap

Tags: java, memory

I am already using -Xmx2G. Can I still go ahead and increase it? Is it dependant of the machine I use

Comment: On a 32 bit systems the limit is 2 Gb, if you need more you need a 64 bit OS. Check out @dogbane answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Java Tuning White Paper](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/tuning.html):

> **4.1.2   Heap Sizing**
>
> The maximum heap size of a Java
>   application is limited by three
>   factors: the process data model
>   (32-bit or 64-bit) and the associated
>   operating system limitations, the
>   amount of virtual memory available on
>   the system, and the amount of physical
>   memory available on the system.
>
> The
>   size of the Java heap for a particular
>   application can never exceed or even
>   reach the maximum virtual address
>   space of the process data model. For a
>   32-bit process model, the maximum
>   virtual address size of the process is
>   typically 4 GB, though some operating
>   systems limit this to 2 GB or 3 GB.
>   The maximum heap size is typically
>   -Xmx3800m (1600m) for 2 GB limits), though the actual limitation is
>   application dependent.

Comment: `though some operating systems limit this to 2 GB or 3 GB`. Very true. It would be interesting to see a list of OS+Service pack in combination with JVM-version and hw-architecture listing the actual limits.

Answer (score 0):

Why not experiment by running java with different heap options until it complains. Of course its dependent, if your machine only has 64k then you cant very well expect it to have the same heap capability of a multi gigabyte monster !

Comment: Experimenting is not possible, because I am supposed to run my program on different machines that I don't have access now